# How can I reset default programs in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, default-settings

By mistake I had changed default program with other files and now all of my files and programs seem to have been changed to word documents, and they do not open. I cannot even open the internet any more in order to find a solution.

I have tried opening files using different methods, but for some reason, it seems to request that I download something. If I click `open` it opens a webpage, which then closes before loading.

How can I go back to my original settings? If possible, I would like as much detail as possible.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you changed default program with other files?
What happens when you press the windows key+r and type cmd?

Comment: Are you able to enter Safe Mode on boot? If so, does the problem persist? If not, can you run virus & malware scans?

Answer (score 3):

You can restore the default program from Control panel

`Control Panel->Programs->Default Programs->Set Program access and computer default ->Microsoft Windows->OK`

You can also control which application has to open a particular file from Control Panel->Programs->Default Programs->Set Default Program`

For a single file format you can right click on the file and select `Open with` and `Choose Default Program` and select your necessary application.